# How do I merge(?) two different dataframe but by rows that they share in common?

Tags: r, statistics

[image: This is what I wanted to do]

so I am trying to merge these dataframe, therefore as a table with name / proportion / degree_length

but the condition is that I will only use the rows which they share same *name*.

How should I code this? Thank you

Comment: `merge(dat1, dat2, by = "name")`

Comment: Your use of images to display what you are hoping for is very clear and demonstrative, so I think my previous comment will be enough. If not, though, however clear your images are, they are just images, and you may find a negative reaction by many (for good reasons, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). A better strategy is to include a sample of both frames and the expected output, all via an unambiguous data sample such as the output from `dput`; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Young Jun Jeong!

Comment: Thank you so much r2evans! Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow so didn't know about the rules